# import csv delete all existing records then import

Tags: ruby, csv, import

I am importing a CSV of data however I would like to delete all of the current users data first, then import.  Effectively replacing all of the current users data with the newly uploaded data.. I cant figure it out, any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have, which doest work :( It DELETES all users data not just the current users data.. wipes out the entire inventory table instead of rows with the current_user.id

```
class Inventory < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user

def self.import(file, user_id)
  Inventory.destroy_all
  allowed_attributes = [ "user_id", "id","description","part_number","price","created_at","updated_at", "alternate_part_number", "condition_code", "qty", "mfg_code", "serial_number", "part_comments"]
  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    inventory = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
    inventory.attributes = row.to_hash.select { |k,v| allowed_attributes.include? k }
    inventory.user_id = user_id
    inventory.save!
  end
end
```

Comment: Just a small remark: if inventory is always imported for a single user, then `import` should be an instance method on `User` class, not a class method on `Inventory`. Also, is it `Inventory` or `InventoryItem`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will destroy all inventory records, not just the current user's:

```
Inventory.destroy_all
```

Instead, this will destroy inventories which belong to the current user:

```
Inventory.where(user_id: user_id).destroy_all
```